# Composer is failing to execute git clone

Tags: php, docker-compose, composer-php

I am trying to get an example github repo to run on my machine in docker (https://github.com/FoxyCart/foxyclient-php-example)

Docker is running containers for NGINX, PHP and composer. When I use docker-compose up I get the error from the Composer container. I am using the official composer image version 1.9.

> [RuntimeException]
>
> composer_1  |
> Failed to execute git clone --no-checkout
> 'git@github.com:FoxyCart/foxyclient-php.git'
> '/app/vendor/foxycart/foxyclient'

> && cd '/app/vendor/foxycart/foxyclient'

> && git remote add composer
> 'git@github.com:FoxyCart/foxyclient-php.git'

> && git fetch composer &&
> git remote set-url origin 'git@github.com:FoxyCart/foxyclient-php.git'

> && git remote set-url composer
> 'git@github.com:FoxyCart/foxyclient-php.git'

> install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no- > dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-> progress] [--no-suggest] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-
> autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--
> ignore-platform-reqs] [--] []

From what I understand in composer.json included in the example repo it is trying to install the foxyclient package(https://github.com/FoxyCart/foxyclient-php). It seems to be a public repo so I am unsure why it is having trouble cloning it.

Edit:

At first I thought that the composer image needed git installed. I created a custom image that installed git but that did not fix the problem so I went back to the official image.

I created a personal access token in case the issue was not being able to answer a prompt to enter my gtihub username and password to clone to repo but that did not fix it either.

Thank you

Comment: There's no way to know which command in that giant one-liner failed. Split them up into individual commands until you figure out which one specifically is failing.

Comment: @Sammitch these are commands that the composer is running. I'm not sure how I would split them up.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? How are these commands run?